# On 'npm outdated' error: Only tag, version, and range are supported

Tags: node.js, npm

There are "named" references in my `package.json` (npm 7.20.3)

```
 "bootstrap-legacy": "npm:bootstrap@4.6.0",
 "sass-legacy": "npm:sass@1.32.13",
```

But after this `npm outdated` stop working:

> npm ERR! Only tag, version, and range are supported npm ERR! A
> complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> ..\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-09T09_14_26_242Z-debug.log

Nothing interesting in the log

Do we have any workaround for this? Any key for the `outdated` command ? Other command to list outdated packages? Solved in later `npm` versions?

P.S. `npm install` works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2800) which you can follow and like in order to get it fixed. There seems not to be a general solution to the alias issue, but in some cases the usage of aliases can be avoided.